# AVAssetTrack.duration is shorter than AVURLAsset.duration

Tags: ios, video, avmutablecomposition

This is weird, after hours' testing I still can't figure it out.

Ok, this is what I'm going to do: merge two videos, that is to append one after another.

I shoot two videos, then have two urls. Then I created two AVURLAsset using :

```
 AVURLAsset* video1 = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:url1 options:options];
 AVURLAsset* video2 = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:url2 options:options];
```

Then I get the corresponding tracks:

```
AVAssetTrack *videoAsset1Track = [[video1 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
AVAssetTrack *videoAsset2Track = [[video2 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then, I have several CMTime to compare:

```
CMTime endtime1 = videoAsset1Track.timeRange.duration;
CMTime endtime2 = videoAsset2Track.timeRange.duration;
CMTime starttime1 = videoAsset1Track.timeRange.start;
CMTime starttime2 = videoAsset2Track.timeRange.start;
```

Strange things then happen. When I Log :

```
NSLog(@"video 1 duration : %f , start : %f, end : %f ", CMTimeGetSeconds(video1.duration), CMTimeGetSeconds(starttime1), CMTimeGetSeconds(endtime1));
NSLog(@"video 2 duration : %f , start : %f, end : %f ", CMTimeGetSeconds(video2.duration), CMTimeGetSeconds(starttime2), CMTimeGetSeconds(endtime2));
```

It always comes with :
 `video 1 duration : 4.738333 , start : 0.000000, end : 4.738333 
 video 2 duration : 4.736871 , start : 0.000000, end : 3.090011`
Video 1 is always ok, while video 2: track's duration < asset's duration.

By the way, I'm using `GPUImageVideoCamera` and `GPUImageMovieWriter`(But I don't think it matters, for video 1 is always ok) to shooting videos and merge.

---

**Edit**

God I have another super weird observation:

Whenever I shoot the video, the duration of the track is always shorter than the asset's. 
However if I check it for the second time, all will be ok... That's...
What do I do during the two check times? I just use an `AVPlayer` to play the url...

---

**Edit Again**

Guys this is super super weird!!! I just play the url, and world becomes better. I don't know why, but at least find a way out...(No, this way sometimes still doesn't work...)

Comment: Can you loop through all the tracks in video2 to see if there's another track (maybe audio) with a longer duration for some reason? Also, which of the two durations (4.73 or 3.09) do you think is correct?

Comment: I also checked the audio's duration, which is equal to the asset's, which is the correct one(the longer one).

Comment: But I have no idea why it will be shorter... the process are nearly the same except for the second time I'll go to merge them...

Comment: I'm trying to implement a function like instagram to merge videos, how do they implement the function... using the same method(I mean , by ``AVMutableComposition``)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok After a tiring investigation, I finally got the point.

It finally prove to be related with `GPUImageVideoCamera`. And anyone who is also using the library may pay attention: if you only write `[GPUImageMovieWriter finishRecording]`, it is not enough(which means, the file is not completed). 

You have to write `[videoCamera stopCameraCapture]` to close the camera capture and then the file is closed and completed.

WEIRD...